# Is it risky to install a theft-protection system?

Tags: identity-theft, bios

I recently bought a Dell laptop and found out that [Dell recommends to install a theft-protection system called LoJack](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln147225/computrace-lojack-for-laptops-frequently-asked-questions-faq-?lang=en). It is a system installed on the BIOS; if the laptop is stolen, it is possible to connect to their website to locate the laptop, delete files on it, etc. Since it sits on the BIOS, it cannot be removed by formatting the hard-drive.

It seems like a good security measure. On the other hand, it seems to give a lot of power to the company behind LoJack; apparently, any of their employees can now control my laptop remotely.

So, my question is: do I put myself on risk by installing such a theft-protection system on my laptop? Are there known cases where a laptop was taken control of using such a system?

Comment: A lot of people currently uses it, and they business is around protection. If someone abused the system to control a notebook without permission, they would lose a lot of customers. I think it's a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the good old wikipedia info on [LoJack for laptops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoJack_for_Laptops).

As mentioned by the page, it is NOT a remote control tools, but piece of tools that trigger as "beacon" and send information back to its designated home server.

Perhaps the biggest concern is not about the computer being hijack by more sophisticated malware(as mentioned in the wiki page about rootkit installation through vulnerabilities), but the company able to monetize from the demographic data the server collected.